How to convert wp equations into linear algebra equations?
I am reading this paper [1], wherein the authors first formulated a safety constraint in terms of wp equations. Then, they converted the equations into linear algebra form.
As per section 4.3, their safety constraint takes the following form -
$\phi_H = \lor_{i=1}^{N} WP(\land_{j=1}^{H} P_i \mathbf{\chi}_j + q_i \leq 0, f)$
Then, in section 4.4, they convert it into linear algebraic form  -
$\phi = \lor_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=0}^{H-1} G_{i,j}u_j + h_i \leq 0$
I am unsure of the process used to create the matrices $G$ and $h$. I'd also like to know how the $\sum$ operator was included in the above line.
Here is my understanding -
I believe the variable $u_j$ is a part of the polynomial expansion of $\mathbf{\chi}_j$, since we have this expression in section 4.1 - $f(x,u) = Ax + Bu + c + \Delta$. And then in section 4.2, we have the expression - "Recall that our environment approximation f is a linear function with bounded error, so we have constraints over the symbolic states and actions: $\chi_{i+1} = A\chi_i + B\omega_i + c + \Delta$, where $\Delta$ is an unknown vector with elements in $[−ε, ε]$."
Also since the $\lor_{i=1}^{N}$ is common in both equations written above, I am assuming that -
$WP(\land_{j=1}^{H} P_i \mathbf{\chi}_j + q_i \leq 0, f) = \sum_{j=0}^{H-1} G_{i,j}u_j + h_i \leq 0$
Please let me know if something is unclear in my question.
[1]. Anderson, Greg, Swarat Chaudhuri, and Isil Dillig. "Guiding Safe Exploration with Weakest Preconditions." International Conference on Learning Representations (ICLR). 2023.
